# Zooming on specific element with d3js

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I recently just found d3js and this block of example code when looking for a good way to zoom on elements: [the example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/2206590). I'm trying to use the same method of zooming, but instead of using json to populate the svg and body, I want to just zoom on specific html elements.I'm new to using d3 so I'm not sure what exactly I'm doing wrong, but heres my code so far:

JS:

```
window.onload=function(){
  var width = 400,
    height = 400,
    centered;

  var projection = d3.geo.albersUsa()
    .scale(1070)
    .translate([width / 2, height / 2]);

var path = d3.geo.path()
    .projection(projection);

var svg = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .on("click", clicked);
var circle = svg.append("circle")
         .attr("class", "logo")
         .attr("cx", 225)
         .attr("cy", 225)
         .attr("r", 20)
         .style("fill", "transparent")      
         .style("stroke", "black")    
         .style("stroke-width", 0.25)
         .attr("d", path)
         .on("click", clicked)
          .on("mouseout", function(){ 
               d3.select(this)
                   .style("fill", "transparent");
         });

function clicked(d) {
  console.log("clicked");
  var x, y, k;

  if (d && centered !== d) {
    var centroid = path.centroid(d);
    x = centroid[0];
    y = centroid[1];
    k = 4;
    centered = d;
  } else {
    x = width / 2;
    y = height / 2;
    k = 1;
    centered = null;
  }

  circle.selectAll("path")
      .classed("active", centered && function(d) { return d === centered; });

  circle.transition()
      .duration(750)
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")scale(" + k + ")translate(" + -x + "," + -y + ")")
      .style("stroke-width", 1.5 / k + "px");
}
        }
```

HTML:

```
<script src="d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="index.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<svg id="mySvg" width="80" height="80">
      <defs id="mdef">
        <pattern id="image" x="0" y="0" height="40" width="40">
          <image x="0" y="0" width="40" height="40" xlink:href="image1.png"></image>
        </pattern>
  </defs>

</body>
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EHMM5/) of what I have so far. As you can see it calls the click function and styles the stroke width, but it doesn't zoom on the object.

Comment: You've got quite a lot of unnecessary stuff in there and I'm not sure what you're looking for. Something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/EHMM5/1/)?

Comment: Yes, thats exactly what I'm looking for! Thanks for the snippet. And sorry about the unnecessary stuff, sometimes I don't bother removing code snippets that I don't think will effect the end result.